# Backwards compatible openssh configuration?

Tags: ssh, configuration

My ~/.ssh/config contains this:

```
HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-dss
```

I copy this configuration across many systems. Recently I copied it to a system running OpenSSH v5.3 and that entry is now an error:

```
/home/sparr/.ssh/config line 3: Bad protocol 2 host key algorithms '+ssh-dss'.
```

Is there a way to make this configuration backwards compatible, so that the new option is used for newer clients and ignored for older clients?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old OpenSSH does not support the `+` sign. But you can write it the way you list all of the algoriths (that are common for these versions):

`HostKeyAlgorithms ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss`

Or just really update your server and do not use DSA host keys, since they are insecure.